# Value being cleared in DOM by ng-model AngularJS

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm very new to AngularJS and have run into something I can't seem to figure out on my own. I am working on an invoice application and when I am returning a value AND a ng-model then the value is being calculated but is never set in the DOM. Which then in turn never updates the subtotal I am trying to calculate.

**rowController.cshtml**

```
<tr id="row-{{$index+1}}" class="item-row" ng-repeat="item in itemRows">
    <td><input type="text" class="text-right" placeholder="$0.00" ng-model="hrsQty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="text-right" placeholder="$0.00" ng-model="ratePrice" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="text-right" placeholder="$0.00" value="{{rowTotal(hrsQty, ratePrice) | currency}}" ng-model="amountSum[$index]" /></td>
</tr>
```

This bit of code takes hrsQty * ratePrice and returns it's value into the last input text. The value that is returned will be sent through a `for` loop

**Controller.js**

```
function InvoiceController($scope) {
$scope.itemRows = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
$scope.hrsQty;
$scope.ratePrice;
$scope.amountSum = [];
$scope.subTotal;

$scope.rowTotal = function (hrsQty, ratePrice) {
    return hrsQty * ratePrice;
};

$scope.subTotal = function () {
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0, v; v = $scope.amountSum[i]; i++) {
        sum += +v;
    }
    return sum;
};
}
```

If I remove the ng-model then my calculation returns perfectly, but if I put the ng-model back in and remove `value="{{rowTotal(hrsQty, ratePrice) | currency}}"` then my subtotal calculations works great. It's when the two are combined that `value="{{rowTotal(hrsQty, ratePrice) | currency}}"` is never set in the DOM or is being removed.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should be amountSum field be editable or just for informational purposes?

Comment: That's something I still need to change. It will be readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need not ng-model but just show some value. `ng-model` should be used to allow user to change something in your model.

So check this solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/eo37EXog0FWVr1lTn1Cw?p=preview

Looks like something you need.

Comment: I've been messing around with the plnkr solution and got that all implemented into my solution. When I enter in the first field 33.33 and in the 2nd field 3 the subTotal and the rowTotal are different. How can I fix that? Also what does |0 mean? Thank you!

Comment: I found this - http://jsfiddle.net/slav123/75m7e/3/
I edited my .js and code to follow that example and now am able to get back the right results. Thank you again @Valentyn

Comment: about totals are different - its because I've rounded result (by "|0"). I've updated plunker.